# Bringing computer hardware to Albania crossing several Balkan countries

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, balkans

if I have to bring cryptocurrency mining hardware (A disassembled PC and several GPUs) from Germany to Albania. What are the problems I could face on border control and customs in the countries I am crossing (I am travelling by car)?

The borders being crossed would be:

- Germany / Austria.
- Austria / Slovenia.
- Slovenia / Croatia.
- Croatia / Bosnia.
- Bosnia / Montenegro.
- Montenegro / Albania.

Would I have to declare the goods for some of the customs and pay taxes to legally transport them?

**UPDATE**
Would it be different / possible / less expensive to do so by flying instead? I tend to think that given the border to cross would be only one.

**UPDATE**
Would I have to pay taxes and declare goods even if the hardware is for me and the transportation is not being done to sell it or leave it in that country being crossed? (Except the final destination being Albania though the hardware is not meant to be sold there)

Comment: As long as you stay within the EU you shouldn't have any issues. However any border crossings between the EU and non-EU states, or between non-EU states, will imply declaring the hardware, and possibly paying taxes and duties (which you should be able to reclaim on exit). There may be ways to avoid paying and reclaiming for each country you cross, but expect quite a bit of paperwork. Is the hardware staying in Albania, or do you intend to bring it back to the EU at some point? If the latter, you could consider an ATA carnet.

Comment: The hardware is supposed to stay in Albania, however I do not exclude the possibility of bringing it back at a later stage...from a quick google search I could see that the ATA carnet would be valid only if the goods are brought back within one year period...

Comment: Yes, it's only meant for short duration temporary imports, usually for stuff like exhibitions or for bringing equipment for a shooting, etc. You may be better off shipping the hardware via a courier service (e.g. UPS, DHL, Fedex, TNT...) so they handle all the hassle of the taxes and duties to be paid.

Comment: I thought about it but I see this a as risky option, as I am afraid the packages may arrive damaged or other unfortunate accidents may happen. That would be the same I think (Maybe less risky) by flying there and have the components transported as additional luggage.

Comment: Pack well and don't forget to declare the right value for insurance purposes. All those components got to you that way, possibly several times on their way from the manufacturer...

Comment: And yes, it would probably much easier if you fly as you have to cross only one border. Whether it's less expensive probably depends on how much hardware you have to bring (i.e. if that fits in your standard check-in allowance or not).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! I'll put some more thinking about it at this stage ;).

Comment: You could take a ferry from Italy. Then it would be one crossing out of the EU.

Comment: This has been flagged as off-topic. Why? It might be too broad but it's certainly about travel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry, I don't see any indication about travelling in the OPs question. And mining machines are specialised hardware used for commercial purpose, so whatever reason the OP has to take it (cheaper energy?) it has nothing to do with travelling.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travelling, but exporting hardware needed fo exercising commercial activity (bitcoin mining) abroad.

Comment: How come this has "nothing to do with travelling"? I never mentioned I am bringing the miner there to exercise commercial activities. According to what I have specified, I might be carrying them with me to show them to a friend and them bring them back (As I also wrote in a comment, I might be taking them back at some point)....Also tinkering and playing with mining machines/hardware is also a very diffused activity which sometimes, especially on latter times, concerns more hobbyist than entrependeurs. What if I was indicating music instruments? Aren't they also used to make money by some?

Comment: @DanubianSailor What? The asker explicitly says that they’ll be travelling from Germany to Albania by car and wants to know about the relevant customs legislation. So what if that travel is for commercial purposes? This site is in no way restricted to leisure travel. [Reposted because my bad editing made the first version incomprehensible but that was too long ago to just edit.]

Answer (score 2):

In most countries the import tax or custom duties are usually assessed on what you are importing and what it holds in value. Depending on how old your computer and graphics cards are and what they hold in current resale value will be biggest factor if you will end up paying import tax or custom duties.

The [Albanian Customs website](http://www.dogana.gov.al/english/c/168/174/195/cash-declaration) states:

> **Each individual**, Albanian or foreigner, entering to or leaving from the territory of the Republic of Albania, **is obliged to declare the** cash, any currency, precious metals or gems, **valuable items**, antiquaries, **exceeding the value of 1 000 000 ALL** (one million) or this sum in other currencies as well as the purpose of carrying them for which is needed to be presented the justifying documents.

Or in short:

> *Each individual is obliged to declare the valuable items exceeding the value of 1 000 000 ALL.*

With the current exchange rate  1€ = 121ALL, if the **total** of everything you are importing exceeds 8,250€ (or 1,000,000 ALL) you **must** declare it, and if possible show proof of purchase.

If you're travelling with your spouse, this declaration threshold will increase as you will be 2 *individuals* and thereby the treshold of 1,000,000ALL per person x 2 people (you and your spouse) will become 2,000,000ALL or 16,500€.

**TL;DR:**
You don't need declare as long as the total of what you are importing does not exceed 1,000,000ALL or approximately 8,250€ according to the [Albanian Customs website](http://www.dogana.gov.al/english/c/168/174/195/cash-declaration).

Comment: Although, the wording says "valuable items", what is meant here is items that could be used to smuggle in or out currency, for instance gold jewellery, ie. items that don't depreciate in value. A car is often worth more than that for instance. It is unlikely they would ask you to declare your car for this purpose. The computer is already depreciated to some extent probably not even exceeding this amount.

Comment: I'm not sure about Albania but I know that some countries don't calculate cash thresholds like that. Travelling with your spouse does not necessarily double the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

In most countries, it is possibly to do a **temporary import**. The above-mentioned ATA carnet is used in all countries you want to enter, including [Albania](http://www.atacarnet.in/country/albania.html).

The German Customs Office explains re-export like this: [Temporary admission](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Businesses/Movement-of-goods/Import/Procedures/Temporary-admission/temporary-admission_node.html)

The concept of this is similar to driving a car into another country. While you use the car there, it's a temporary import.

Although the carnet document is valid one year only, in some countries, it can be "replaced" with a new carnet which extends the period of the temporary import. Again, this is the [case](http://www.atacarnet.in/country/albania.html) with Albania. To be sure if such an extension is actually possible, you would have to contact the Albanian customs authorities, as the actual [treaty document](http://www.wcoomd.org/en/about-us/legal-instruments/~/media/2D53E23AA1A64EF68B9AC708C6281DC8.ashx) states this possibility with a "may".

For eventual re-import to Germany, you would need a [Nämlichkeitsbescheinigung](https://www.zoll.de/DE/Privatpersonen/Reisen/Rueckkehr-aus-einem-Nicht-EU-Staat/Zoll-und-Steuern/Rueckwaren/rueckwaren_node.html) (official page in English doesn't seem to exist).